# Linkend List copy constructor

Tags: java, linked-list, copy-constructor

I am having problems with the copy constructor of a Linkend List in Java.
The list I am trying to copy has a size of 3, when I use the copy constructor the list is empty.

When I try this with the clone method everything works great.
I have look a this for a quite a while and I get the feeling it is so obvious. I just
dont see it, here is the code.

```
public class Employee {

    private String name;
    private double salary;

    public Employee(String name, double salary){

        this.name = name;
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public void setname(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setsalary(double salary){
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public String getname(){
        return this.name;
    }

    public double getsalary(){
        return this.salary;
    }
}


    public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Employees employees = new Employees();
        employees.add(new Employee("Employee1", 2500.00));
        employees.add(new Employee("Employee2", 2400.00));
        employees.add(new Employee("Employee3", 2000.00));

        Employees employeesCopy2 = new Employees(employees);
        Employees employeesCopy = (Employees) employees.clone();

        System.out.println(employees.size());
        System.out.println(employeesCopy2.size());
        System.out.println(employeesCopy.size());
    }

}

    import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Employees extends LinkedList<Employee> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private LinkedList<Employee> employees;

    public Employees(){ 

        employees = new LinkedList<Employee>();
    }

    public Employees(Employees w){

        employees = new LinkedList<Employee>(w);
    }

    public void addWerknemer(Employee w){
        employees.add(w);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

This is homework, but when I wanted to add the tag is showed that the tag was no longer is use.

Comment: Why are you extending LinkedList and creating a new LinkedList too?
Since Employees extends LinkedList, it IS a LinkedList.

Comment: The *homework* tag is [deprecated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated), you don't have to use it anymore. But it is still a good thing to mention it in the question, IMO. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your confusion comes from the fact, that `Employees` both **is** a list and **contains** a list. When you use

```
employees.add(new Employee("Employee1", 2500.00));
```

you add the employee to the *outer* list. When you use

```
employees.addWerknemer(new Employee("Employee1", 2500.00));
```

you add the employee to the *inner* list. Since you have overwritten the constructor `Employees(Employees es)`, this **will not** clone the outer list, but only the inner. And since you haven't overwritten `clone()`, it **will** clone the outer list, but **not** the inner. This is rather messy and also most probably not intended by you. I therefore propose one of the following changes:

**1. [Preferred] Employees only contains a list and not extends one**
Skip the `extends LinkedList<Employee>` and only work with an internal list. You will have to use your method `addWerknemer(Employee emp)` to add to your list (or change it's name to `add`). You will have to implement `size` and `clone` as well as other methods that you wish to use. If you want to be really clean about this, you can even make the class `implement List` or `implement Collection` or so. This way you can still treat your class as a `java.util.Collection`. I don't think that this would be neccessary in your case though. Also you would need to implement all of the interfaces methods (there are many). An example implementation would look like this. You still have to implement `size`, etc.

```
public class Employees /*implements List<Employees>*/ {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private LinkedList<Employee> employees;

    public Employees(){ 
        employees = new LinkedList<Employee>();
    }

    public Employees(Employees w){
        employees = new LinkedList<Employee>(w);
    }

    public void add(Employee w){
        employees.add(w);
    }

    public Employees clone() {
        return employees.clone();
    }

    // add more methods as you need them (like remove, get, size, etc)
}
```

**2. Employees only extends `LinkedList` and doesn't contain one**
Throw away your methods `addWerknemer(Employee emp)` and the copy constructor `Employees(Employees)` as well as your internal list. This way you will not overwrite the existing implementations of `LinkedList`. This approach is more or less useless because you basically just rename `LinkedList` to `Employees` and add/change nothing. Therefore I wouldn't recommend this approach.

Answer (score 4):

I think this:

```
public class Employees extends LinkedList<Employee> {

    private LinkedList<Employee> employees;
```

will create a world of confusion. You're both extending a list, and within that class you're maintaining a separate list. When you call `addWerknemer()` you add to the inner list. What happens when you call `get()` ? Since you've not overridden this, you're calling `get()` on the base class, and that's a *different* list!

Without inspecting the rest of your code, I suspect this is a fundamental source of problems.

You have two choices:

1. `Employees` extends `List`
2. `Employees` contains a `List`

I would prefer the second. You can change the underlying collection (e.g. a `Set`, perhaps a `Map` for better lookup performance) and not change the exposed interface.

Comment: Actually `add` will add to the object itself, `addWerknemer` will add to the list contained inside the object.

Comment: It will indeed. This demonstrates the mind-warping confusion further! Thx for pointing that out

Answer (score 1):

You are extending `LinkedList`, but also have a `LinkedList` inside that extension. Initially you use the `add` method to add `Employee` instances, so they get added to the `Employees` list itself, but when you use the copy constructor, you copy those employees to the `employees` field inside your `Employees` class.

When you call the `size()` method, it will use the `LinkedList` of the `Employees` object itself, so in the first list it is 3, but on the second it is 0 as now the employees are in the contained list and not in the object itself.

In this case you probably should **not** extend `LinkedList`. Or if you do, then don't use a separate field like `employees` which also contains a LinkedList.